# Google app engine No handlers matched this URL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform

i am going to call firebase Http request from a cron job i setup on google app engine.the cron job is deployed successfully but it did not trigger the firebase url as i think i am missing some setting in the web.xml file or in other files.
In the log viewer i see this type of info "No handlers matched this URL"
Any one have any idea.Any would be appreciated.
Following is my cron.xml setting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/cron</url>
        <target>beta</target>
        <description>Keymitt cron job</description>
        <schedule>every 1 minutes</schedule>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

this is my web.xml setting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloAppEngine</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.company.HelloAppEngine</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloAppEngine</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>KeymittCron</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.company.KeymittCron</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>KeymittCron</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cron</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and this is my associated WebServlet

```
@WebServlet(name = "KeymittCron",value = "/cron")
public class KeymittCron extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(KeymittCron.class.getName());
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
      //  super.doGet(req, resp);
        URL url=new URL("httplink");
        HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        int requestCode=connection.getResponseCode();
        if(requestCode==200){
            _logger.info("firebase link triggered successfully");
            _logger.info("Executed cron job");
        }
        else{
            _logger.info("Error while triggering firebase link");
        }
        connection.disconnect();
        resp.setStatus(200);
        resp.getWriter().println("Done");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //
        doGet(req,resp);
    }
}
```

And this is my Logger info
[image]

Comment: You are sending the cron job to a specific target service.  Have you deployed that target service using the same config files?  Try removing `<target>beta</target>`

Answer (score 1):

My answer here may be relevant - [Google Cloud App Engine cron job - not calling the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56470226/google-cloud-app-engine-cron-job-not-calling-the-service/56470829#56470829)

Basically, you may need this in your `appengine-web.xml`:

```
<service>beta</service>
```

The `<target>` you specify in your `cron.xml` must match the `<service>` you define in your `appengine-web.xml`