# Google Cloud App Engine cron job - not calling the service

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cron

I've successfully deployed a Cron job to App Engine, for a Java application using the App Engine Standard environment. It deploys successfully, however the cron job fails, and when I check the log, it isn't calling the correct service:

```
"GET /my-app HTTP/1.1" 404 - - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)"
"my-project.appspot.com"
```

Other cron jobs that are working look like this (note that the last part shows the *service name* and not just the project name):

```
"GET /my-app HTTP/1.1" 404 - - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)"
"my-service.my-project.appspot.com"
```

Here is my **cron.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/my-app</url>
        <description>my app</description>
        <schedule>every 1 minutes from 00:00 to 23:00</schedule>
        <timezone>Europe/Paris</timezone>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

And my **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>my-app</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.my.package.MyApp</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>my-app</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>my-app</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

And my servlet definition (this is a Cloud Endpoint app, which uses a Java servlet):

```
@WebServlet(
        name = "my-app",
        urlPatterns = {"/my-app"}
)
public class MyApp extends HttpServlet {
   ...
```

And my **appengine-web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  ....    

  <application>my-project</application>
  <service>my-app</service>

  ....

</appengine-web-app>
```

Why isn't the cron job calling the service? The service is also correctly deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron):

The following example creates a basic cron job that runs daily:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/tasks/summary</url>
    <target>beta</target>
    <description>daily summary job</description>
    <schedule>every 24 hours</schedule>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

> The target specification is optional and is the name of a
>   service/version. If present, the target is prepended to your app's
>   hostname, causing the job to be routed to that service/version. If no
>   target is specified, the job will run in the versions of the default
>   service that are configured for traffic.

I think this is what is happening in your case. Since you have not specified the `target`, the cron job is hitting the /my-app route on default service. Mention the service name in the target.

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh. I just beat you to the solution however the additional info is useful - thanks for the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

My **cron.xml** needed a `<target>` that matches the `<service>` in my **appengine-web.xml**

**cron.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/my-app</url>
        <!-- <target> required -->
        <target>my-app</target>
        <description>my app</description>
        <schedule>every 1 minutes from 00:00 to 23:00</schedule>
        <timezone>Europe/Paris</timezone>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  ....    

  <application>my-project</application>
  <!-- cron <target> must match service -->
  <service>my-app</service>

  ....

</appengine-web-app>
```